# Chmod permission issue when running a docker container

Tags: docker, permissions, containers, chmod

I'm trying to run a simple-ca container (https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/simple-ca) in docker (running in a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04.4) but every time I run the docker command

```
docker run   --name simple-ca   -p 80:8080   -p 443:8443   -e CERT_TLS_DNS=ca.mycompany.com   -e CA_CN=MyCompany-CA   -v /var/lib/simple-ca/ssl:/ssl   quay.io/jcmoraisjr/simple-ca:latest
```

I get the error

```
chmod: private: Operation not permitted
```

I have already granted systemd-network ownership of the folder /var/lib/simple-ca/ and ran the command

```
 /bin/bash -c 'chown $(docker run --rm quay.io/jcmoraisjr/simple-ca id -u lighttpd) /var/lib/simple-ca/ssl'
```

to grant lighthttpd rights on the SSL folder

Anyone have any idea on what may have went wrong?

Comment: It looks like [this line is failing](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/simple-ca/blob/fdf49d2b6d61308ade36fc7e0dacf78688843181/start.sh#L44). Can you look inside `/var/lib/simple-ca/` for files that are not owned by uid 100?

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue that caused the container to fail to start. I had to remove the folder /var/lib/simple-ca and let the systemd startup re-create it with Lighttpd user id.
Once that was done, I used the container console access to directly edit the CA config files and the whole simple-ca was working as expected.